# Inserting record to nested array using MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB called topic

```
topic{
    topic_title: 'thread',
    reply{
        reply_title: 'thread',
        reply_content: 'content'
        reply_created: "2013-06-18 17:54:04" 
    }

}
```

I wanted to add a reply to the topic like:

```
topic{
    topic_title: 'thread',
    reply{
        reply_title: 'thread',
        reply_content: 'content'
        reply_created: "2013-06-18 17:54:04" 
    }
    {
        reply_title: 'reply1',
        reply_content: 'reply2'
        reply_created: "2013-06-18 17:57:04" 
            }
}
```

my code goes like this:

```
   $reply = array(
                            "reply_title" => $title,
                            "reply_content" =>$content,
                            "reply_created" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
    $document = array('$push' => array("reply" => $reply));

    $id = new MongoId($topicid);
    $topic->update(array("_id"=>$id),$document);
```

and it did something like this

```
     topic{
           topic_title: 'replytitle'
           reply {
                    reply_title: "replytitle"
                    reply_content: "replycontent"
                    reply_created: "2013-06-18 17:57:12"
                 }

          }
      reply{
            reply{
                    reply_title: "replytitle"
                    reply_content: "replycontent"
                    reply_created: "2013-06-18 17:57:12"
             }
            reply{
                    reply_title: "replytitle"
                    reply_content: "replycontent"
                    reply_created: "2013-06-18 17:57:12"
             }
           }
```

I am really having a hard time doing a simple thing. which is add a reply to the reply array. Any help out there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on what your document structure is since what you posted isn't valid JSON. But assuming that `topic.reply` is supposed to be an array of documents, you can use the [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) operator like this:

```
$topic->update( array( "_id" => $id ), array( "$push" => array( "topic.reply", $reply ) ) );
```